# How to join multiple tables using LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: join, linq-to-sql

I'm quite new to linq, so please bear with me.

I'm working on a asp.net webpage and I want to add a "search function" (textbox where user inputs name or surname or both or just parts of it and gets back all related information).  I have two tables ("Person" and "Application") and I want to display some columns from Person (name and surname) and some from Application (score, position,...). I know how I could do it using sql, but I want to learn more about linq and thus I want to do it using linq.

For now I got two main ideas:

1.)

```
    var person = dataContext.GetTable<Person>();
    var application = dataContext.GetTable<Application>();
    var p1 = from p in Person
             where(p.Name.Contains(tokens[0]) || p.Surname.Contains(tokens[1]))
             select new {Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, Surname = p.Surname}; //or maybe without this line

 //I don't know how to do the following properly
 var result = from a in Application
                 where a.FK_Application.Equals(index)  //just to get the "right" type of application
                 //this is not right, but I don't know how to do it better
                 join p1
                 on p1.Id == a.FK_Person
```

2.) The other idea is just to go through "Application" and instead of "join p1 ..." to use

```
var result = from a in Application
             where a.FK_Application.Equals(index)  //just to get the "right" type of application
             join p from Person
             on p.Id == a.FK_Person
             where p.Name.Contains(tokens[0]) || p.Surname.Contains(tokens[1])
```

I think that first idea is better for queries without the first "where" condition, which I also intended to use. Regardless of what is better (faster), I still don't know how to do it using linq. Also in the end I wanted to display / select just some parts (columns) of the result (joined tables + filtering conditions).

I really want to know how to do such things using linq as I'll be dealing also with some similar problems with local data, where I can use only linq.
Could somebody please explain me how to do it, I spent days trying to figure it out and searching on the Internet for answers.

Comment: So, this is Linq-to-SQL?

Comment: Yes this is Linq-to-SQl (in C#, Framework 4.0). I totally forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = from a in dataContext.Applications
             join p in dataContext.Persons
             on p.Id equals a.FK_Person
             where (p.Name.Contains("blah") || p.Surname.Contains("foo")) && a.FK_Application == index
             select new { Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, Surname = p.Surname, a.Score, a.Position };
```

Well as Odrahn pointed out, this will give you flat results, with possibly many rows for a single person, since a person could join on multiple applications that all have the same FK.  Here's a way to search all the right people, and then add on the relevant application to the results:

```
var p1 = from p in dataContext.Persons
             where(p.Name.Contains(tokens[0]) || p.Surname.Contains(tokens[1]))
             select new {
                Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name, Surname = p.Surname,
                BestApplication = dataContext.Applications.FirstOrDefault(a => a.FK_Application == index /* && ????  */); 
         };
```

Sorry - it looks like this second query will result in a roundtrip per person, so it clearly won't be scalable.  I assumed L2S would handle it better.

Comment: Thanks, this was just what I needed. Could you please help me out how to enable sorting. I bind the result to gridview. I have to provide my own sorting method, I thought about using "result.OrderBy...", but result is local to other method, I can't make it global because it is "var", I tried making a special class and declaring result as global: "IQueryable<ResultsRow> result;" But then I don't know how to cast result from above code to "IQueryable<ResultsRow> result". Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  You'll probably want to ask a new one on SO so more people will see it.  But, if I'm understanding your correctly, you want to bind this to a grid such that all your columns will be sortable by default?  If so, you need to get these results into a special container that supports this; linq has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Something like this?  http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidA43B425AC6738E217B16ABB9FD8C089DDE856FF5.aspx?s=datagridview

Comment: I wanted to declare anonymous variables as global or use them in methods, which I can't. I saw some answers on how to solve the problem, create a special class, which I did, but I didn't knew that you had to overwrite some methods, ... Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: The closest you could come to making anonymous variables global / passing them to methods would be to declare them as *dynamic*.  You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer this properly, I need to know if Application and Person are directly related (i.e. does Person have many Applications)? From reading your post, I'm assuming that they are because Application seems to have a foreign key to person.

If so, then you could create a custom PersonModel which will be populated by the fields you need from the different entities like this:

```
class PersonModel
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Surname { get; set; }
    List<int> Scores { get; set; }
    List<int> Positions { get; set; }
}
```

Then to populate it, you'd do the following:

```
// Select the correct person based on Name and Surname inputs
var person = dataContext.Persons.Where(p => p.Name.Contains("firstname") || p.Name.Contains("surname")).FirstOrDefault(); 
// Get the first person we find (note, there may be many - do you need to account for this?)

if (person != null)
{
    var scores = new List<int>();
    var positions = new List<int>();

    scores.AddRange(person.Applications.Select(i => i.Score);
    positions.AddRange(person.Applications.Select(i => i.Position);

    var personModel = new PersonModel
                          {
                              Name = person.Name,
                              Surname = person.Surname,
                              Scores = scores,
                              Positions = positions
                          };
}
```

Because of your relationship between Person and Application, where a person can have many applications, I've had to account for the possibility of there being many scores and positions (hence the List).

Also note that I've used lambda expressions instead of plain linqToSql for simple selecting so that you can visualise easily what's going on.

Comment: I don't think projecting his results onto a new object is his problem.  I think his question makes clear (especially considering his two code samples) that he wants to *join* these two tables together - using linq.

Comment: Alright ... fair point. But in your code answer, I don't see anywhere how you account for the one to many relationship. You should be dealing with dataContext.Persons (not a single Person). Also, you haven't selected his many scores and positions in your anonymous return value. I was just trying to interpret the poor chaps question because he's obviously having serious trouble.

Comment: You're right.  When he queries for his people, and then joins to applications, he might end up with multiple rows for the same person since there are "many" corresponding applications.  He's going to have to figure out how he wants to deal with that, or maybe he already has.  The code I have him will get him the join he's looking for, hopefully he's aware of the issue you've pointed out.  I also edited to add scores/positions.  Again, hopefully he's aware that there could be many applications per person, and so multiple rows for each person.

Comment: One thing though, I *was* dealing with the whole collection of Persons, I just typed it as DataContext.Person - I was confused for a minute about how good the pluralization was in L2S - it's fixed now.